# Circular reference in Entity Framework Core. Is Circular reference good or bad?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have situation of one to many relationship between CriminalChargeCategory and CriminalChargeType. I have configure foreign key relationship in EF but it causes the circular reference. So, is circular reference good or bad? 
My classes looks like

```
 public class CriminalChargeCategory 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<CriminalChargeType> CriminalChargeTypes { get; set; }
    }

 public class CriminalChargeType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int criminalChargeCategoryID { get; set; }
        public CriminalChargeCategory CriminalChargeCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: so `CriminalChargeCategory.CriminalChargeTypes` is just a navigation property correct?

Comment: Good or bad in regards to what? As you said, those properties are as expected when configuring a one-to-many relationship

Comment: Yeah we can say it is a navigation property. Like Every CriminalChargeCategory has list of CriminalChargeType.

Comment: since  both of classes have reference to each other so circular reference is expected. So when i load data from database, the main object has so many circular reference which makes object heavy. So do i need to avoid circular reference by putting navigation property in just one class only? But it make sense to put two way navigation property.

Comment: but in reality will you use the nav property? - if not leave it out

Comment: Yeah i am using nav property from both sides.